# Allow user to select random blog bost

Tags: python, django, url, random, view

I've started using Django 2.0 and Python 3.6.3 to develop a website which will display customized "Posts", as in a blog Post.

I want the user to be able to click a button that basically says "Random Post". This button will take them to a template which loads a random blog post.

Here's my Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ... other fields
    ... other fields

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here are some relevant views:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_list.html'

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
```

Here is my problematic view:

```
import random

def random_post(request):
    post_ids = Post.objects.all().values_list('post_id', flat=True) 
    random_obj = Post.objects.get(post_id=random.choice(post_ids))
    context = {'random_post': random_obj,}
    return render(request, 'blog/random_post.html', context)
```

Here I am trying to create a Values List of all post_id values for the Post model. Then I'm trying to get a random choice from this Values List, which would be a random id. Then I'm trying to create a context and render a template using this logic.

Here are relevant urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/', 
        views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post_detail'),
    path('post/random/<int:pk>', views.random_post, name='random_post'),
```

Needless to say this is not working.

If I leave off the "int:pk" it renders a blank template with no data - no blog Post. If I include the , it causes an error - No Arguments Found. I assume that no data is being queried in the view, or the data isn't being properly sent from the view to the template.

I am new to Django. I appreciate your help!

Comment: 1) Could you post a stack trace?              
2) `random_post` does not accept any argument `pk`. Maybe remove it from the url pattern and try.                      
3) Rest of the code seems fine

Comment: Can you clarify the behaviour you want? Either a) user goes to "/post/random/" which on that page displays a random post, refreshing the page would show a different one; or, b) user goes to "/post/random" which picks a random ID then redirects the user to "/post/random/<id>", refreshing the page would stay on that page and show the same post.

Comment: I will look into stack trace. I have tried taking out "pk" and it loads the right template, but no data rendered.

I'd prefer the user go to <id> and be forced to click the "random post" button again to get a new post. In this case, if they reload the same page, so be it.

Comment: Line by line, I wonder if... 1. I'm correctly creating a values_list for the Post model. 2. If I'm correctly grabbing an object whose id is the same as the random choice (from the list of IDs) 3. If my context is correct - I honestly can't wrap my head around context for some reason 4. If I should render or redirect, and if my arguments are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the behaviour you want, your URLs should be:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/random/', views.random_post, name='random_post'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', 
        views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post_detail'),
]
```

and your random_post view is:

```
def random_post(request):
    post_count = Post.objects.all().count()
    random_val = random.randint(1, post_count-1)
    post_id = Post.objects.values_list('post_id', flat=True)[random_val]
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=post_id)
```

This makes two queries - one to get the count of all posts, and one to get ID of the post in the random position. The reason for doing this is that then you don't have to get all of the IDs from the database - if you have thousands of posts, that would be very inefficient.

Comment: Thank you! This almost works, I think. The issue that I'm having is that it's only loading one record over and over. In this case, it is the most recent post. However, it's loading data finally, so I really appreciate the help. Any guesses? Seems like it would have to do with the randomint logic, or some kind of small syntax issue?

Comment: Well, like I said in the comment, this picks a random number and redirects you to that page, so if you refresh it you will get the same post; you would need to go to /post/random/ again to be redirected to a new random one.

Comment: Yes thank you. I have a button, with a 'random_post' url. I have an update. It is not including the first record. I have 3 blog posts, and it selects 2 and 3 randomly, but not 1. So - do I need to put "0" as the randint first value? UPDATE: I tried changing to 0 and it works! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the view that works.

```
def random_post(request):
    post_count = Post.objects.all().count()  
    random_val = random.randint(0, post_count-1)  
    post_id = Post.objects.values_list('post_id', flat=True)[random_val]   
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=post_id) #Redirect to post detail view
```